# issues on making triangles with css borders

Tags: css, css-shapes

I've just making an arrow in css with this code:

```css
        .icon{
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            border: solid transparent;
            border-width: 10px;
            border-left-color: aquamarine;
            border-top-color: saddlebrown;
            border-right-color: salmon;
            border-bottom-color: steelblue;
        }
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```

correct triangles:

[image: correct triangles]

and the result was 4 correct triangles
**but when I use the same code in somewhere else the result is looks like pic below** that the division box width and height isn't the same.

incorrect triangles:

[image: incorrect triangles]

Comment: somewhere else means where you are using ?

Comment: In **Somewhere else** there is a rule that overrides your *.icon* `height: 0;` rule.

Comment: I wrote exact the same code just in another file! that contains `height: 0;`

Comment: Your code works fine. Maybe you have set padding to all divs

Answer (score 0):

you should just work wtih `Positions` that make the `width` and `height` works...

Answer (score 0):

try this shorthand code.
just change your color/style/width of border according to your preference.

```
    .icon{
    border-color: yellow blue red green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 200px 200px 200px 200px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Actually, he has just set some padding to this div somewhere else. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zcqvbhLv/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding you have set elsewhere

```
.icon{
    ...
    padding: 0;
    ...
}
```